# Python: How to get some images from a video in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video

How can I extract frames from a video file using Python3?

For example, I want to get 16 picture from a video and combine them into a 4x4 grid.

I don't want 16 separate images at the end, I want one image containing 16 frames from the video.

----Edit----

```
import av

container = av.open('/home/uguraba/Downloads/equals/equals.mp4')
video = next(s for s in container.streams)
for packet in container.demux(video):
    for frame in packet.decode():
        if frame.index %3000==0:
            frame.to_image().save('/home/uguraba/Downloads/equals/frame-%04d.jpg' % frame.index)
```

By using this script i can get frames. There will be lots of frames saved. Can i take specific frames like 5000-7500-10000 ?

Also my question is how can i see the total frame number ?

Comment: I just researched, i found moviepy (http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) and openCV but i'm not sure, these libraries can do this task ?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use PyMedia or PyAV to access image data and PIL or Pillow to manipulate it in desired form(s).

These libraries have plenty of examples, so with basic knowledge about the video muxing/demuxing and picture editing you should be able to do it pretty quickly. It's not so complicated as it would seem at first.

Essentially, you demux the video stream into frames, going frame by frame.

You get the picture either in its original (e.g. JPEG) or raw form and push it into PIL/Pillow.

You do with it what you want, resizing etc... - PIL provides all necessary stuff.

And then you paste it into one big image at desired position.

That's all.

Comment: WOw, finally a down vote, and on a good answer too. If you know better, then give a better answer instead of down voting without any aparent reason. I am not going to write whole code here, it has miles. And internet is full of examples.

Comment: Hi i did not gave any vote. I'm just research PyAV. I installed by using pip, try to run basic example on http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/ I will try to figure how to run, because even basic example gives an error.

Comment: Which example exactly, and what error it is throwing? BTW, OpenCV is also not a bad idea, honestly.

Comment: Hi, i just update my question. I try to use pyAV. But it will gave an error. You can see on first post.

Comment: OK, StopIteration means that you hit the end of movie in this case. It occurs after first next(). So, are you sure your video contains data? But this may have something to do with Py3, so try it, just try, on Python 2 to see whether it still raises an error. Well if it doesn't work at all, try PyMedia, it is similar.  Also FFMPEG wrapper. These libs have an advantage over OpenCV just because are specialized for just that, and therefore are light weight.

Comment: thank you, for your response, i solve the StopIteration problem, as you say, it hit the end and because of this reason the loop is not working. Now i can get some frames, but i couldn't find how many frames in video ?

Comment: Find out how long it is (in seconds), and what is its frame rate, then just multiply these two and you get total number of frames. But PyAV should give you this info as such somewhere.

Comment: I think there will be a function which returns total frame number. If i couldn't find this method, i will use your idea.

Comment: It should be there. And if it is, then it is listed in DOCs. If it isn't then it means that you can get other info that will allow you to calculate the number of frames. But, yes, it would be odd if such basic info is not available directly.

Comment: There will be frames attribute on streams part of the class, but it will return always zero. Do you think is that what i'm trying to find ?

Comment: I am not sure. I will know more when I get to this problem, but at the moment I am working on something else. One idea that occurred to me is to see whether you can iterate over whole stream without unpacking the frame. In this case, you can count to the end or to the frame you wish. Also, it would be better that you leave the question in the state before this, and the solved part add as an answer if you want. Then ask another Q about PyAV.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with OpenCV3, the Python wrapper and Numpy.
First you need to do is capture the frames then save them separately and finally paste them all in a bigger matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)

# capture the 4 frames
_, frame1 = cap.read()
_, frame2 = cap.read()
_, frame3 = cap.read()
_, frame4 = cap.read()

# 'glue' the frames using numpy and vertigal/horizontal stacks
big_frame = np.vstack((np.hstack((frame1, frame2)),
                       np.hstack((frame3, frame4))))

# Show a 4x4 unique frame
cv2.imshow('result', big_frame)

cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

To compile and install OpenCV3 and Numpy in Python3 you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/).

You can implement a kind of "control panel" from 4 different video sources with something like that:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source1)
cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source2)
cam3 = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source3)
cam4 = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source4)

while True:
    more1, frame_cam1 = cam1.read()
    more2, frame_cam2 = cam2.read()
    more3, frame_cam3 = cam3.read()
    more4, frame_cam4 = cam4.read()

    if not all([more1, more2, more3, more4]) or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF in (ord('q'), ord('Q')):
        break

    big_frame = np.vstack((np.hstack((frame_cam1, frame_cam2)),
                           np.hstack((frame_cam3, frame_cam4))))

    # Show a 4x4 unique frame
    cv2.imshow('result', big_frame)

print('END. One or more sources ended.')
```

Comment: OpenCV OK I agree, but I'd still use PIL for image processing. Because now you have to turn an ndarray() back to OpenCV to save it somehow as an image. I mean, if it isnt bmp. Then ndarray().tostring() and simple header will do the trick.

Comment: The above example shows multiple instances of OpenCV running.  Is this even possible?  I could not get the above example to work.

Comment: I personally wrote and run the script some time ago. It was working with the opencv version at this time. What problem did you experience when running it?

Comment: different tech? what do you mean @CrazyMerlin? The question is not fixed to an specific library, it asks how to do it in py3.

Comment: @Hamlett The OP is clearly using PyAV and not OpenCV. OpenCV can do it, sure, but so can PyAV, so why change?

Comment: @CrazyMerlin You should check author edits before judging. You are wrong. My post was released before the OP edits the post adding code with PyAV. Anyway, with the PyAV present in it, my code is valid. The OP is asking for a solution in Py3.